# Batch request - Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

All,

I am trying to implement a batch request to Dynamics CRM with the following source code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpPatchCrmApi(string resource, string data)
{
    string uniq = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    MultipartContent content = new MultipartContent("mixed", "batch_" + uniq);
    HttpRequestMessage batchRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, CrmBaseUrl + "/api/data/v8.0/$batch");
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, CrmBaseUrl + resource);
    request.Content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpMessageContent query = new HttpMessageContent(request);

    content.Add(query);

    batchRequest.Content = content;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await RbWebApi.SendAsync(batchRequest);

    return response;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting "**400 Bad request**"

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments here is the stack trace of the request from fiddler:

```
POST https://Hidden.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/$batch HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV.... very long string
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_7b6e3c60-1284-4958-a39a-4653af21833c"
Host: Hidden.api.crm4.dynamics.com
Content-Length: 313
Expect: 100-continue

--batch_7b6e3c60-1284-4958-a39a-4653af21833c
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

POST /api/data/v8.0/my_recurringgifts HTTP/1.1
Host: Hidden.api.crm4.dynamics.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"my_name":"slavi"}
--batch_7b6e3c60-1284-4958-a39a-4653af21833c--
```

While writing the code I was inspiring myself from [here](http://bartwullems.blogspot.dk/2015/01/aspnet-web-api-request-batching.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734003/applying-default-headers-to-multi-part-request-content)

Comment: I would use Fiddler to make sure the requests that you send look like the examples from the SDK: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607719.aspx

Comment: Hi Polsh, updated :) I been looking at it all along but can't see difference/reason for bad request :(

Answer (score 5):

I think your request is wrong. 
You must build the request Body **EXACTLY** like [defined by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607719.aspx)

This means the Blank lines must be there at the right place all the attributes must exist in the body (like "--changeset_XXX" for example) and as I see you dont meet this requirements.

I just build a Request in Postman against my CRM and it worked:

---

**URL**

```
https://yourTenant.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/$batch
```

---

**Headers**

```
OData-MaxVersion:4.0
OData-Version:4.0
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Bearer aVeryLongStringTokenHere
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_1234567
```

---

**Body**

```
--batch_1234567
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_555666

--changeset_555666
Content-Type:application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID:1

POST https://yourTenant.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:application/json;type=entry

{name: 'BatchJobTest788'}
--changeset_555666
Content-Type:application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID:2

POST https://yourTenant.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:application/json;type=entry

{new_name: 'BatchJobTest348'}
--changeset_555666--
--batch_1234567--
```

---

**Additional Remarks:**

- The Content-Type of your Header holds your BatchId
- The Content-Type of your Batch holds your ChangesetId (if it is a change to data)
- Before starting to programm REST calls try to define them in a REST tool like POSTMAN and make them work. Then build the working request in your code.
- [Here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/) a good explanation-source for the batching in CRM