# CRM WebApi batch request

Tags: javascript, jquery, odata, dynamics-crm

With this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607719.aspx, I'm trying to create a batch request to delete all quotedetails on a quote.
I'm using jquery's ajax to do the request:

```
$.ajax(
{
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://crm/api/data/v8.0/$batch',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_' + batchId,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    data: payload
});
```

And this is the payload:

```
–batch_SuL11egVC7
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_Sj74vxbGYr

–changeset_Sj74vxbGYr
Content-Type:application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID:1

DELETE crm/.../quotedetails(cc9b9ba8-4570-e611-80ba-0050568a6c2d) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry
–changeset_Sj74vxbGYr
Content-Type:application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID:2

DELETE crm/.../quotedetails(cd9b9ba8-4570-e611-80ba-0050568a6c2d) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry
–changeset_Sj74vxbGYr--

-batch_SuL11egVC7--
```

I'm not getting an error, but the quotedetails aren't deleted.
This is the response:

```
--batchresponse_a3304387-0e91-4097-b9f8-a207da3aa845--
```

I've also found this example and I'm trying to replicate it with Postman: [Batch request - Dynamics CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750981/batch-request-dynamics-crm)

Headers:

```
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_123456
Accept:application/json
Odata-MaxVersion:4.0
Odata-Version:4.0
```

Body:

```
–-batch_123456
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_123457

–-changeset_123457
Content-Type:application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID:1

POST http://onpremisesurl/api/data/v8.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:application/json;type=entry

{name: 'batch acount 1'}
–-changeset_123457
Content-Type:application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID:2

POST http://onpremisesurl/api/data/v8.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:application/json;type=entry

{name: 'batch acount 2'}
–-changeset_123457--
--batch_123456--
```

The first one doesn't delete the accounts and the second doesn't create the accounts.

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I'v done some further testing and found out where it goes wrong.

First, in the last sample, creating two accounts, the object should be this:

```
{ "name": "batch acount 2"}
```

And in the first example, when deleting records, you need to send an empty object. This is a working example for deleting accounts:

```
--batch_AAA123
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=changeset_BBB456

--changeset_BBB456
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID: 1

DELETE http://tenanturl/api/data/v8.1/accounts(4deb1677-427b-e611-80bb-0050568a6c2d) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{}
--changeset_BBB456
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-ID: 2

DELETE http://tenanturl/api/data/v8.1/accounts(52eb1677-427b-e611-80bb-0050568a6c2d) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{}
--changeset_BBB456--
--batch_AAA123--
```

And somehow one of the two dashes before batch and changeset was different:

```
--batch_AAA123
--changeset_BBB456
```

I hope this helps somebody else as well.